# Unable to translate the description of my custom plugin in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using poedit to translate my plugin, and everything is working fine, the only problem is the description of my plugin, I am unable to translate it using the below the code in my `.pot` file.

```
#: wp-related-articles-acf.php:4
msgid "Plugin to show the related posts."
msgstr ""
```

In plugin file

```
Plugin Name: Related Articles
Description: Plugin to show the related posts
Author: Sandy
Version: 1.0
Text Domain: wp-related-articles-acf
Domain Path: /languages
```

Comment: for the translate function you use it this ways ?  : `_e('Your test', 'wp-related-articles-acf')`. And you po has the same name ? like `wp-related-articles-acf-en_EN.po` ? 
They all need to get the same name. I went trough this not so long ago

Comment: For example if you use translate function with a shorten text domain like: `_e('Your test', 'wraa')`, your plugin text domain needs to be `Text Domain: wraa` and the po file `wraa-en_EN.po`

Comment: The other translations of my plugin are working fine like, the error messages, fields name, i did that already with `_e` but how can i translate the description which is in the commented area on the top of my plugin file

Comment: Ooh sorry i read too fast  ...  this is weird. I have made some plugins, and i just checked if the description could be translated and yes. It seems that we code it the same way, except that i have not this line `Domain Path: /languages`. I'm also using a folder called `languages` and it's working. Maybe you could try to remove it ?

Comment: @AlexVand, thanks, i tried after removing the domain path, but its still not translating the description.